# How to escape a $ in a bash command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do the following command:

```
 curl -k -i -X POST -d ' { "path" : "/" }' 
    https://david:mypa$$@example.com:9092/files/browse
```

How would I properly send the above command, given that my password is `mypa$$` ?

Comment: Single Quote it: `'https://david:mypa$$@example.com:9092/files/browse'`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either enclosing them in single quotes or by prepending them with backslashes, like `\$\$`.